# The Sims 4 flash drive for cc?

Tags: the-sims-4

I was wondering if I can put all my CC on a flash drive. I know I can't put the whole game on there, that would amazing since I have a 2TB flash drive, but I know I can't. but I can put all my CC on there right and the game will see it when I direct it to it?

Comment: What does cc mean?

Comment: CC = custom content